# /home/webapp: No such file or directory elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deploy my ruby app on aws using elastic beanstalk. Following error occur.
[pass log](https://pastebin.com/MmzLRsQJ)

```
App 20278 stdout: intializing git
App 20278 stderr: error: could not lock config file /home/webapp/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
App 20278 stderr: sh: line 0: cd: /home/webapp: No such file or directory
```

[eb log](https://pastebin.com/mVn1iCWi)
Please tell me how to fix this

Edit: When I run script locally I get an error like `chmod: changing permissions of '.netrc': Operation not permitted`. I think this line is the cause for app to not work. Content of `.netrc` is

```
machine github.com
login soumjo
password 123456
```

Sice during script run, it ask for github username and password in terminal.
git_intializer.rb

```
system("echo intializing git")
`git config --global user.name soumjo
`git config --global user.email soumjo@gmail.com`
`cd && touch .netrc`
`chmod 600 .netrc`
File.write(".netrc",
    <<-HEREDOC
machine github.com
login soumjo
password 123456
HEREDOC
    )
```

Comment: need write access.  on .gitconfig file

Comment: how to do it? donno

Comment: share what u have inside `.ebextensions` ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding following lines in .ebextensions config file solves this issue

```
commands:
  01_mkdir_webapp_dir:
    # use the test directive to create the directory
    # if the mkdir command fails the rest of this directive is ignored
    test: 'mkdir /home/webapp'
    command: 'ls -la /home/webapp'
  02_chown_webapp_dir:
    command: 'chown webapp:webapp /home/webapp'
  03_chmod_webapp_dir:
    command: 'chmod 700 /home/webapp'
```

But I have new issue which will talk in another thread. Thanks for the support.